# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium; No matching distribution found for selenium while installing Selenium on Python3.6.5

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pip, installation

```
pip install selenium
```

throws error as:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium;
No matching distribution found for selenium
```

Please guide as to how to proceed

Comment: have you tried `pip3 install selenium` ?

Comment: Yes, it throws the error: pip3 is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Are you on Linux or windows?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` then do the pip3 install again

Comment: I am using Windows 7 professional; sudo apt-get install python3-pip throws the same error of not being recognized as an internal/external command

Comment: Try this `C:\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe install selenium`

Comment: what dose `pip --version` give you?

Comment: Oh sorry, I wouldn't know for windows

Comment: Can you run `pip -V` and `pip install -vvv selenium` and add the output of both commands to the question? If the output gets too big, use some online service like pastebin.com.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium;
No matching distribution found for selenium
```

...implies that the *Python Client* was unable to install the **Selenium** related modules.

Your main issue probhably with either with the **pip** version or the *Python* installation.

### Solution

- Uninstall the current *Python* installation.
- As you are on *Windows 7 professional OS* use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before the new installation of *Python Client*.
- Download and install a fresh version of compatible [**Python 3.6.5**](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-365/) binary/executable.
- Ensure you are using latest version of **pip** (latest version 18.0 is available now):

  ```
  C:\Users\username>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  Collecting pip
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
      100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 1.3MB 544kB/s
  Installing collected packages: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
      Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
        Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
  Successfully installed pip-18.0
  ```
- Install latest version of **Selenium**:

  ```
  C:\Users\username>pip install selenium
  Collecting selenium
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/53/9cafbb616d20c7624ff31bcabd82e5cc9823206267664e68aa8acdde4629/selenium-3.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (898kB)
      100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 901kB 380kB/s
  Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: urllib3 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.22)
  Installing collected packages: selenium
    Found existing installation: selenium 3.12.0
      Uninstalling selenium-3.12.0:
        Successfully uninstalled selenium-3.12.0
  Successfully installed selenium-3.14.0
  ```
- Or:

  ```
  C:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe install selenium
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have conda, so I used it and it worked like a charm!

```
$conda install selenium
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of typing in pip install silenium I just entered: "pip.exe install selenium" and this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Deactivate proxy Settings in Internet Explorer
2. Run pycharm in Windows 10 as Administrator
3. Then Upgrade pip with: `pip install --upgrade pip`
4. Install Selenium with: `pip3 install selenium`