# ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver' from 'selenium' error using Selenium and WebDriver through Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, importerror

I wanted to code a program with selenium, so I wanted to test it but:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

When Im running this program, it says:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver' from 'selenium'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver' from 'selenium'
```

...implies that there was an `ImportError` when you tried to import `webdriver` from the `selenium` module.

---

### Reason

This `ImportError` is observed when you try to execute the line:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

without installing **Selenium**.

---

### Solution

The very first step to use Selenium will be to install [Selenium Python bindings](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) using the following command:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

or upgrade *Selenium Python bindings* using the following command:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Python : no module named selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium/48269228#48269228)
- [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium; No matching distribution found for selenium while installing Selenium on Python3.6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702565/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-selenium-no-matching-di/53705238#53705238)